# What is the difference between hit me vs hit me off in American English?

Tags: difference, vocabulary, expressions

while I listened  I song **Cole Swindell - Hope You Get Lonely Tonight** in a part it said this:

> You got my number baby **hit me up**,

its said **hit me up** okay I understand what is hit and me but what is the different with **hit me** and **hit me up**   I asked this because I heard both way in american english and read in blogs too

Comment: Your title doesn't reflect your question!

Comment: why? @StoneyB I am  asked about what is the different between hit me and hit me off then my title said " hit me vs hit me off in english american what are its different?"

Comment: The body of your question asks about *hit me **up***. ... and by the way, we ask "What is the difference between X and Y?"

Comment: ah okay I wiil edited again my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Hit me up" here is slang for "call me." The whole line says "because you have my phone number, you can and should call me on the phone."

Comment: so then for example with my girlfriend could I say her "hey dearling hit me up I miss you a lot"? note: she is from california

Comment: You can say many things to a girlfriend, even one from California, but I suggest that you avoid slang. It is way too easy to use slang in a way that has an inadvertent meaning or for it to be misunderstood by the listener. I'd stick with "dearling" though; few women that I have known well would not be charmed by that term, provided that it comes from an appropriate person.